# How to preserve Appium session between multiple testng class

Tags: java, appium

I am automating Android application using Appium, I have One Base Class with Setup and Tear down (In setup initialization appium session and in teardown destroying session ).

This Base Class I inherited in all testng classes, now for each test class Appium new session generated.

So My question is that How we maintain appium session through out the all class once it generate for any class.

Thanks
Sadik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented this approach using Singlton design pattern here is approach:

```
public class SingltonFactory{

    private static SingltonFactory instance = new SingltonFactory();
    private static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    private SingltonFactory() {
    }

    // Get the only object available
    public static SingltonFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // Get the only object available
    public void setDriver(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver1) {
        driver = driver1;
    }

    public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> getAppiumDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
```

}

Add initialize SingltonFactory in your before test cases and assign driver object like below:

```
AppiumFactory appiumFactory = AppiumFactory.getInstance();
if(appiumFactory.getAppiumDriver() == null) {
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);                
}
else{
   driver = appiumFactory.getAppiumDriver();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same without inheriting base class.

Step1 -> Initialize driver object in your set up i.e your setup method as                   `driver=new AndroidDriver(url,caps);`

Step 2-> If you have any Utility or Constant class, call its constructor and pass driver as a parameter e.g. `new Constants(driver);`
Note: You can mark driver as a static variable if you only need one driver instance.

Step 3->
Whenever you wish to access driver, access it as Constant.driver or initialize driver object at class level.

Comment: Can you share some piece of code, I tried but it is working getting Nullpointer exception

Answer (score 1):

I also have same requirement, its a **Gradle** project and i use gradle script to execute my testcases,
Requirement: Have to preserve or have to retrieve an Appium session (driver) using session ID So that we can avoid **re initializing** each time **between testcases**

Environment:
Multiple test cases(>50 scenarios) run based on the source tag in sequence. 
Gradle script include parameters
App on **android** dos`t need a re-initialize each time

**What did i try:** 1. Tried to Write driver info to a file and retrive each time when i start a new scenario(setSessionID class in private in Appium)

Create Appium(local) class that can use session id + Appium **APIs** , but that is hectic and will end up maintaining something already is available

```
   DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //migrate to gradle params later after demo
    dc.setCapability("deviceName", "XX30");
    dc.setCapability("udid", System.getProperty("hubUdid"));
    dc.setCapability("appPackage", "com.bbbbb.bbb.bbb.primary");
    dc.setCapability("appActivity", "..Activity");
    dc.setCapability("autoLaunch",false);
    dc.setCapability("dontStopAppOnReset",true);
    dc.setCapability("noReset", "true");
    driver_hub = Android.initialize(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), dc);
```