# WebDriver using Appium: Starting new remote server every time for Android?

Tags: android, webdriver, testng, appium

I am creating test cases for testing a website using Webdriver / Appium for Android. I am also running these tests using TestNG in the XML file.

Each one of my test cases is in a separate class and I have been needing to start a new remote session for every test/class so every class need this setup() and a new remote session is started every time a different class runs.

Is there a way to only start one session and just use that session for all the tests?

```
 @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

         DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
         cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
         cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Note 4");
         cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Chrome");
         driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);        
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: You should use singleton design pattern like post: [StackOverFlow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743214/how-to-preserve-appium-session-between-multiple-testng-class/34829502#34829502)

Comment: @TomZheng - please select and mark an answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

You should use singleton design pattern like post:

I have posted in below link:

[How to preserve Appium session between multiple testng class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743214/how-to-preserve-appium-session-between-multiple-testng-class/34829502#34829502)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@BeforeSuite` for your `setup()`. In your testng.xml specify your `<classes>` inside the `<test> </test>` block. This shall do the needful. Something like this :

```
@BeforeSuite
public void setup() throws MalformedURLException...
```

&&

```
<suite name="MyTestSuite" verbose="1" >
    <test name=TestName">
        <classes>
            <class name="xyz.OneTestClass" />
            <class name ="xyz.AnotherTestClass"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to run multiple test cases in one turn:

`driver.closeApp();
 driver.lauchApp();`

It may help you.